# Burninate [tiles]; Retag as [live-tiles]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

A majority of the questions tagged with [tiles](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tiles) (*27 questions*) appear to be about the [live-tiles](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/live-tiles) (*42 questions*) introduced in Windows 8.

I don't think the tag should be added as a synonym, since "Tiles" could be referring to a few different things. ([Apache Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/), [Tile Bluetooth Tracker](https://www.thetileapp.com/), [Tiles Tab Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tiles/bpjknlfokkbpdhafbdccnndgchglnfhj?hl=en), <s>[Floor Tiles](https://www.tileshop.com/category/tile/floor+tile+material.do)</s>, etc.)

**The [tiles](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tiles) tag should be burninated. Any relevant questions should be retagged as [live-tiles](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/live-tiles)**

Comment: I'm not convinced questions about Floor Tiles would be on-topic on SU ;)

Comment: I'd suggest [tag:windows-live-tiles] or [tag:windows-tiles] instead... it's not immediately obvious that [tag:live-tiles] is a Windows thing.